# How to get my iPhone app listed in iPhone's native Photos app share menu?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, url-scheme

Is it possible to list my iPhone app in iPhone's native photos app's share/send menu?

Some links says not possible. But then how facebook, twitter apps are allowed as those too are native apps not developed by apple.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Sayali

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question refers specifically to the photo app which, as it turns out is a special case

Comment: @Sayali have you done now?

Answer (score 10):

Apple has made a special exception for Facebook and Twitter because of their integration with iOS. Any other apps cannot do that.

**UPDATE:**

[Share extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1) were introduced in iOS 8, which allow developers to add their apps to the list of sharing options in the system menu.

Comment: Some of the documents/office apps allow to do such for opening/editing document. So is it that its not allowed for photos app & possible for files?

Comment: No, the "Open In..." functionality is different from the sharing functionality in the Photos app.

Comment: I dnt want to share it actually. Its like when user taps send in native photos app then a menu appears. In this menu list the app n get the selected image in my appliation. I guess logically it sharing. But then is there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I know where you mean, but unfortunately, you're limited to what Apple gives you.

Comment: Link "Share extensions" is broken